# Django csrf verification failed. request aborted. csrf token missing or incorrect while having everything in place

Tags: ajax, django, django-csrf

i have a html page (done with WYSIWYG), on this page i have a form as big as the page (because i have alot of values i want to be able to send back to my view so i can add the value in the template).

So far everything is working, i'm able to send back my values to my view and add them to the datatabase.

On this page i also have two combobox, and the goal is that once the first one has a selected value, the value get sent back to the view so i can generate the data that goes inside the second combobox.

The problem is that for this operation, i only get the message

> Django csrf verification failed. request aborted. csrf token missing
>   or incorrect

Middleware Settings :

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Template :

```
<form id="frm" method="post" enctype="text/plain">{% csrf_token %}

<select name="typeMvmt" size="1" id="typeMvmt" onchange="document.getElementById('ebIdTypeMVT').value = document.getElementById('typeMvmt').value;veriftype();displayProduit();check();send_post();return false;" style="position:absolute;left:220px;top:5px;width:350px;height:28px;z-index:257;">
<option value="0">-- SELECTIONNER UN TYPE DE MOUVEMENT --</option>
{% for typemouvement in typemouvements %}
<option value={{typemouvement.id}}>{{typemouvement.libelle}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
</form>
```

View :

```
def mouvementCreation(request):
    idMI = 0
    especes = TbEspece.objects.order_by('id')
    typemouvements = TbTypeMouvement.objects.all()
    #Get Mouvement informations

    #Connection to 'erp-site' DB 
    cursor = connections['erp-site'].cursor()
    try:
        #Get Produits list from Espe
        query = "{CALL SP_webGET_PRODUIT_FROM_ESPECE(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)}"
        arguments = (2016, 'C', 0, 10, 'A',)
        cursor.execute(query, arguments)
        produits = dictfetchall(cursor)

        #Get Transporters list
        cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_TRANSPORT}")
        transporters = dictfetchall(cursor)

        #Get Livreur list
        cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_LIVREUR}")
        livreurs = dictfetchall(cursor)
    finally:
        cursor.close()       

    cursor = connections['site'].cursor()
    try:
        #Get Circuit list
        cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_CIRCUIT_FOR_MVT}")
        circuits = dictfetchall(cursor)

        #Get Source list
        cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_SOURCE_FOR_MVT}")
        mvtsources = dictfetchall(cursor)

        #Get Dest list
        cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_DEST_FOR_MVT}")
        destinations = dictfetchall(cursor)

        #Get PontBascule list
        cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_PBASCULE}")
        pontBascules = dictfetchall(cursor)
    finally:
        cursor.close()

    reg_normes = TbRegauxnormes.objects.all()
    ordreexecs = TbOrdreexecution.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get("form_type") == 'formMVT':
            #Handle Elements from first Form
            value = request.POST.get('typeMvmt')
            Req = TbTypeMouvement.objects.filter(value)
            data = getDataQuery(Req)
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type = "application/json")
        elif request.POST.get("form_type") == 'formEspece':
            typemouvement = request.POST.get('idtypemouvement')
            soustype = request.POST.get('idsoustype')
            recolte = request.POST.get('recolte') 
            groupe = request.POST.get('groupe')
            categorie = request.POST.get('categorie')
            code = request.POST.get('code')
            collecte = request.POST.get('collecte')
            vente = request.POST.get('vente')
            stock = request.POST.get('stock')
            achat = request.POST.get('achat')
            transporteur = request.POST.get('codetransporteur')
            blLivreur = request.POST.get('blLivreur', '')
            contratClient = request.POST.get('contratClient')   
            pont1 = request.POST.get('pont1')               # BIGINT
            numTicket = request.POST.get('numTicket')       # INT
            dateheure1 = request.POST.get('dateheure1')     # DATETIME
            poid1 = request.POST.get('poid1')               # INT
            dsd1 = request.POST.get('dsd1')                 # INT
            pont2 = request.POST.get('pont2')               # BIGINT
            dateheure2 = request.POST.get('dateheure2')     # DATETIME
            poid2 = request.POST.get('poid2')               # INT
            dsd2 = request.POST.get('dsd2')                 # INT
            p1p2 = request.POST.get('p1p2')                 # INT
            livreur = request.POST.get('idlivreur')         # BIGINT
            vehicule = request.POST.get('vehicule')         # VARCHAR
            comTicket = request.POST.get('comTicket')       # VARCHAR
            comLogiciel = request.POST.get('comLogiciel')   # VARCHAR
            espece = request.POST.get('especeId')             # BIGINT
            produit = request.POST.get('produitId')           # BIGINT
            #Connection to 'erp-site' DB
            cursor = connections['pontbascule'].cursor()
            try:
            #Get Produits list from Espece
                query = "{CALL SP_webADD_MANUAL_PESEE(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)}"
                arguments = (pont1, numTicket, dateheure1, poid1, dsd1,pont2, numTicket, dateheure2, poid2, dsd2, p1p2,livreur, vehicule,comTicket, comLogiciel,espece, produit)
                cursor.execute(query, arguments)
                idCreatedPesee = cursor.fetchone()
            finally:
                cursor.close()
            cursor = connections['site'].cursor()
            try:
                query = "{CALL SP_webCREATE_MVT_INIT(%s,%s,%s, %s)}"
                arguments = (idCreatedPesee[0], typemouvement, soustype, transporteur)
                cursor.execute(query, arguments)
                idCreatedMVT = dictfetchall(cursor)
            finally:
                cursor.close()
    return render(request, 'mouvementCreation.html', locals())
```

I tried making the same page with just one form i get the same result, so far i only used ajax with Datatable and had no problem, hope someone can share some light on my problem.

I use Firefox, i took a look at the settings cookie etc... but nothing seem to work.

Comment: is there a cookie `csrftoken` set? and if you're using django, why are you bypassing the ORM and doing the manual fetches?

Comment: I'm going to go with no since i didn't notice i had something to setup with the cookie to make the ajax work, how should i use it ? And i don't use the ORM mainly because i need to use stored procedure and it was easier and faster that way.

Comment: with ajax, there's already comprehensive documentation and examples at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#ajax.  Understood about stored procedures.

Comment: Okay i'm going to try that, but i don't really get why implementing this is better than passing the csrf token to the ajax each request

Comment: so, what's not obvious to me is whether you're using a django form or ajax post submission.  if the latter, you need to include the csrf token as a header for your request.

Comment: i'm using ajax post submission (the first combobox call a send_post() function that do the submission.

Comment: understood.  so, if you were using it as a regular django form submission, the csrf token would be included with the post request.  however, because this is ajax, and JS based, the browser doesn't know it has to add that token to the request.  That's why you have to set it up yourself

Comment: I used var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
    }
}); that should give the csrf token to each request but i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: so, csrf is actually a cooke, so you'll have to read the cookie value.  that's why the docs suggest adding the https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/ library to make things easier

Comment: Oh ok, well i wont be able to test that right now but i will try it later and see how it goes and get back to you, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Just try to remove `enctype="text/plain"` from your form. Django can't read your token from plain text payload.